# Anaconda : cannot import name auc_score

Tags: python, anaconda

I try running a python file in spyder of Anaconda with mac, but an ImportError occured.

The python file is running well in Ubuntu. I installed Anaconda because it is said that all kinds of packages are included. The import error is really unexpected and I do not know how to fix the problem.

```
from sklearn.metrics import auc_score
```

> ```
> ImportError: cannot import name auc_score
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auc_score` is apparently not in the namespace...

### **use this instead:**

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score
```

Whichever suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

The right import is `roc_auc_score` instead of `auc_score`.

Its usage is `roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)`.